# How do I create a 'word stream' and 'document stream' in Python?

Tags: python, stream, nlp

I want to take a bunch of text files and combine them all into two arrays - a 'word stream' and a 'document stream'. This is done by counting the total number of word tokens in the corpus then creating the arrays in which each entry in the word stream corresponds to the word associated with that token and the document stream corresponds to the document the word came from.

For example, if the corpus is

```
Doc1: "The cat sat on the mat"
Doc2: "The fox jumped over the dog"
```

The word stream will look like this:

```
WS: 1 2 3 4 1 5 1 6 7 8 1 9
DS: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this, so my question is essentially this: How do I convert a text file into an array of word tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? It's Python3 code, but I think that only matters in the `print` statements. The comments have a couple of notes for future additions...

```
strings = [ 'The cat sat on the mat',           # documents to process
            'The fox jumped over the dog' ]
docstream = []                                  # document indices
wordstream = []                                 # token indices
words = []                                      # tokens themselves

# Return an array of words in the given string. NOTE: this splits up by
# spaces, in real life you might want to split by multiple spaces, newlines,
# tabs, what you have. See regular expressions in the module 're' and
# 're.split(...)'
def tokenize(s):
    return s.split(' ')

# Lookup a token in the wordstream. If not present (yet), append it to the
# wordstream and return the new position. NOTE: in real life you might want
# to fold cases so that 'The' and 'the' are treated the same.
def lookup_token(token):
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] == token:
            print('Found', token, 'at index', i)
            return i
    words.append(token)
    print('Appended', token, 'at index', len(words) - 1)
    return len(words) - 1

# Main starts here
for stringindex in range(len(strings)):
    print('Analyzing string:', strings[stringindex])
    tokens = tokenize(strings[stringindex])
    for t in tokens:
        print('Analyzing token', t, 'from string', stringindex)
        docstream.append(stringindex)
        wordstream.append(lookup_token(t))

# Done.
print(wordstream)
print(docstream)
```

Comment: When docstream prints, it produces an array of 0s and 1s instead of 1s and 2s. Also, to take care of the 'The' and 'the' mistake, I just set the strings to lowercase using .lower()

Comment: True. I used the literal array indices, so 0, and 1.